# Netlify deploy issue on build

Tags: build, netlify, netlify-cli

site link - https://react-chat-page.netlify.app/

github - https://github.com/mrshawnhum/chat-app

[image: Build Error]

I have recently added a redirect file to fix a bug when you refresh the site and I added automatic deploys with netlify-cli to my project. The first time I added Yarn Run Build and received an exit code 127 when attempting to deploy. I manually changed it on netlify to Yarn Build and still receive the same message. I also attempted to clear the cache and manually deploy the site and still receive the same message.

```
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "netlify-cli": "^2.58.0",
    "query-string": "^6.13.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-emoji": "^0.5.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-scroll-to-bottom": "^3.0.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "postbuild": "cp_redirects ./build/",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Netlify will start the build from the root folder of your git repo by default, which doesn't have your package.json file in it, and so Netlify doesn't know how to run `yarn`.

You can change that in the UI settings, see [here](https://community.netlify.com/t/support-guide-what-if-my-project-folder-is-not-the-root-of-my-git-repository/123).